# Why does this code gives an IndentationError?

Tags: python

I can't find a solution for this error below, it's not accepting print or return:

```
>>> vendors = ['cisco','juniper','alcatel','huawei']
>>> for x in vendors:
... print (x)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print (x)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'for' statement on line 1
```

Comment: There needs the be a newline before the `for x in vendors` part.

Comment: Because, as the message says, you didn't indent the line after `for`; the one with `print`. Either indent it or write it on the same line as `for`.

Answer (score 1):

In the REPL, you need to manually type out indentation.

You're trying to loops over elements. Loop bodies are indented